# Htaccess and SEO Friendly Permalink

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, seo, url-rewriting

Now, my permalink appears like that;

http://www.mywebsite.com/readhoroscope?horoscope=gemini

I want to make this permalink like this;

http://www.mywebsite.com/gemini.html

How can I do that by using rewrite in htaccess?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Check the example number 1 and 4 
http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/03/url-rewriting-examples-htaccess.html

Comment: RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ readhoroscope?horoscope=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ readhoroscope?horoscope=$1 this wasn't worked too:(

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^gemini.html$ readhoroscope?horoscope=gemini
```